# Find tickSize Binance

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to find tickSize using this method but it returns an error.

Data:

```
{'symbol': 'FIROUSDT', 'status': 'TRADING', 'baseAsset': 'FIRO', 'baseAssetPrecision': 8, 'quoteAsset': 'USDT', 'quotePrecision': 8, 'quoteAssetPrecision': 8, 'baseCommissionPrecision': 8, 'quoteCommissionPrecision': 8, 'orderTypes': ['LIMIT', 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'MARKET', 'STOP_LOSS_LIMIT', 'TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT'], 'icebergAllowed': True, 'ocoAllowed': True, 'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed': True, 'allowTrailingStop': False, 'isSpotTradingAllowed': True, 'isMarginTradingAllowed': False, 'filters': [{'filterType': 'PRICE_FILTER', 'minPrice': '0.00100000', 'maxPrice': '10000.00000000', 'tickSize': '0.00100000'}, {'filterType': 'PERCENT_PRICE', 'multiplierUp': '5', 'multiplierDown': '0.2', 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.10000000', 'maxQty': '90000.00000000', 'stepSize': '0.10000000'}, {'filterType': 'MIN_NOTIONAL', 'minNotional': '10.00000000', 'applyToMarket': True, 'avgPriceMins': 5}, {'filterType': 'ICEBERG_PARTS', 'limit': 10}, {'filterType': 'MARKET_LOT_SIZE', 'minQty': '0.00000000', 'maxQty': '26259.97721527', 'stepSize': '0.00000000'}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ORDERS', 'maxNumOrders': 200}, {'filterType': 'MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS', 'maxNumAlgoOrders': 5}], 'permissions': ['SPOT']}
```

Code:

```
data = client.get_symbol_info('FIROUSDT')
print(data['filters']['filterType']['PRICE_FILTER']['tickSize'])
```

Error:

```
print(data['filters']['filterType']['PRICE_FILTER']['tickSize'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What's the mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data["filters"]` returns a [List](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp), not a [Dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp), so to access the "PRICE_FILTER" we need to use the index of this filter.

```
[
  {
    "filterType": "PRICE_FILTER",
    "minPrice": "0.00100000",
    "maxPrice": "10000.00000000",
    "tickSize": "0.00100000"
  },
  {
    "filterType": "PERCENT_PRICE",
    "multiplierUp": "5",
    "multiplierDown": "0.2",
    "avgPriceMins": 5
  },
  {
    "filterType": "LOT_SIZE",
    "minQty": "0.10000000",
    "maxQty": "90000.00000000",
    "stepSize": "0.10000000"
  },
  {
    "filterType": "MIN_NOTIONAL",
    "minNotional": "10.00000000",
    "applyToMarket": true,
    "avgPriceMins": 5
  },
  {
    "filterType": "ICEBERG_PARTS",
    "limit": 10
  },
  {
    "filterType": "MARKET_LOT_SIZE",
    "minQty": "0.00000000",
    "maxQty": "26259.97721527",
    "stepSize": "0.00000000"
  },
  {
    "filterType": "MAX_NUM_ORDERS",
    "maxNumOrders": 200
  },
  {
    "filterType": "MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS",
    "maxNumAlgoOrders": 5
  }
]
```

The first filter has a *filterType* of "PRICE_FILTER" so our index is *0* because Python uses 0-based indexing, so to get this filter we use

```py
data["filters"][0]
```

This returns the following dictionary

```
{
  "filterType": "PRICE_FILTER",
  "minPrice": "0.00100000",
  "maxPrice": "10000.00000000",
  "tickSize": "0.00100000"
}
```

So to print the tickSize you can run

```py
print(data['filters'][0]['tickSize'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:

```
info = client.exchange_info(asset)
tickSize = info['symbols'][0]['filters'][0]['tickSize']
print(tickSize)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).